# Docker pull from privately hosted registry for python:3.6.8-slim based image works after push but returns blob unknown after prune

Tags: docker, python-3.6, sonatype, nexus3

For a cron job triggered script, I have used `python:3.6.8-slim` as a base image for my script to run.

The script runs every hour and does so successfully until the `docker system prune` job runs.

After that, the script fails to pull the image with the message `"ERROR: error pulling image configuration: unknown blob"`

When rebuilding and pushing the image to the registry again, the `docker pull` command runs without any problems until the prune job.

I am using sonatype nexus3 as my private docker registry.

I do not understand why the `docker system prune` job is causing this behaviour since the registry nexus3 is running in its very own container.

my cron job:

```
30      *       *       *       *       docker pull my.registry.com/path/name:tag && docker run --rm my.registry.com/path/name:tag
```

my `dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.6.8-slim
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
COPY ./ ./src/
CMD ["python", "src/myscript.py"]
```